# Angular ui-grid dynamically calculate height of the grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

I am using : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-RC.18

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" style="height:765px"></div>
```

When I hard code the value, as shown above, the grid spreads out and everything works as expected.

However, if I do the following...

```
$scope.gridStyle = 'height:'+numRows*rowHeight+'px' //(765px);
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" style="{{gridStyle}}"></div>
```

The height is printed in the div and div widens but the content itself widens to only around 340px. The space that is left is blank, so instead of 25 rows I see only 8. I have to scroll down, while there is a whole 400px free in the grid. The ui-grid-viewport and ui-grid-canvas are both not using this space...

Why can't the ui-grid-viewport use that space?

Comment: As far as I understand the grid does not provide a dynamic height. However, you can attach ui-grid-auto-resize to your grid and it should attempt to fit it to the data. That is how I solved the issue (+ give your grid a way to calculate the height by means of a function, I used ng-class="myStyle()"  where myStyle is just the product between my rowheight and $scope.gridOptions.data.length.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I use `ui-grid - v3.0.0-rc.20` because a [scrolling issue is fixed](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/1926) when you go full height of container. Use the `ui.grid.autoResize` module will dynamically auto resize the grid to fit your data. To calculate the height of your grid use the function below. The `ui-if` is optional to wait until your data is set before rendering.

```js
angular.module('app',['ui.grid','ui.grid.autoResize']).controller('AppController', ['uiGridConstants', function(uiGridConstants) {
    ...
    
    $scope.gridData = {
      rowHeight: 30, // set row height, this is default size
      ...
    };
  
    ...

    $scope.getTableHeight = function() {
       var rowHeight = 30; // your row height
       var headerHeight = 30; // your header height
       return {
          height: ($scope.gridData.data.length * rowHeight + headerHeight) + "px"
       };
    };
      
    ...
```

```html
<div ui-if="gridData.data.length>0" id="grid1" ui-grid="gridData" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize ng-style="getTableHeight()"></div>
```

Comment: Just a note that there may be performance issues using this method as this sets a timer that executes every 250ms to see if the grid size has changed.  Please see my answer about responsive CSS if you don't want to go this route.

Comment: Lets say I have a button onclick of which a new ui-grid row is added, is there a way for me to avoid the 250ms timer execution?

Comment: Acceptable, working solution. Should be in ui-grid manual/tutorial.

Comment: Is there any solution if the rows aren't a constant height? The questioner assumes a constant height, so I opened up a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311664/angular-ui-grid-auto-height-if-rows-have-non-constant-height

Comment: In @tony's answer, function `$scope.getTableHeight` will return an object, we need a string, so `return 'height:' + ($scope.gridData.data.length * rowHeight + headerHeight) + 'px';` works well. And `ng-style` is not work for me, I can use `style="{{getTableHeight()}}"` in html.

Comment: Can anyone please look at this issue also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072428/ui-grid-custom-directive-height-not-getting-updated-when-i-change-the-data

Answer (score 20):

A simpler approach is set use `css` combined with setting the `minRowsToShow` and `virtualizationThreshold` value dynamically.

In stylesheet:

```
.ui-grid, .ui-grid-viewport {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

In code, call the below function every time you change your `data` in `gridOptions`. `maxRowToShow` is the value you pre-defined, for my use case, I set it to 25.

ES5:

```
setMinRowsToShow(){
    //if data length is smaller, we shrink. otherwise we can do pagination.
    $scope.gridOptions.minRowsToShow = Math.min($scope.gridOptions.data.length, $scope.maxRowToShow);
    $scope.gridOptions.virtualizationThreshold = $scope.gridOptions.minRowsToShow ;
}
```

Comment: Considering the simplicity of this fix, it works great - One bug though: If you need expandable grids, it will break scrolling on the nested grids.

Comment: I've been struggling with updating the height on page size changes.  I used your CSS and put the code in your `setMinRowsToShow()` inside `gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged` and worked great for me.

Comment: I am having issue when changing the data length https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072428/ui-grid-custom-directive-height-not-getting-updated-when-i-change-the-data

Comment: This is a great solution as it does not involve absolute heights.

Answer (score 4):

.ui-grid, .ui-grid-viewport,.ui-grid-contents-wrapper, .ui-grid-canvas {
        height: auto !important;
    }

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**:

The HTML was requested so I've pasted it below.

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="my-grid"></div>
```

**ORIGINAL**:

We were able to adequately solve this problem by using responsive CSS (`@media`) that sets the height and width based on screen real estate.  Something like (and clearly you can add more based on your needs):

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .my-grid {
    width: 772px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .my-grid {
    width: 972px;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 768px) {
  .my-grid {
    height: 480px;
  }
}

@media (min-height: 900px) {
  .my-grid {
    height: 615px;
  }
}
```

The best part about this solution is that we need no resize event handling to monitor for grid size changes.  It just works.

Comment: isn't the "style" applied to to my-grid overriding your class settings?

Comment: i don't apply any styles directly to our grid.  I only add a class attribute.  I'll update the example above.

Comment: I see but the fact is that the ui.grid is setting a style by itself, in particular it sets its height attribute... Maybe we have different versione or different conditions.. :/

Comment: Yea, I dunno.  I just know ours works and I don't need to use `!important`.

Answer (score 1):

I like Tony approach. It works, but I decided to implement in different way. Here my comments:

1) I did some tests and when using ng-style, Angular evaluates ng-style content, I mean getTableHeight() function more than once. I put a breakpoint into getTableHeight() function to analyze this.

By the way, ui-if was removed. Now you have ng-if build-in.

2) I prefer to write a service like this:

```
angular.module('angularStart.services').factory('uiGridService', function ($http, $rootScope) {

var factory = {};

factory.getGridHeight = function(gridOptions) {

    var length = gridOptions.data.length;
    var rowHeight = 30; // your row height
    var headerHeight = 40; // your header height
    var filterHeight = 40; // your filter height

    return length * rowHeight + headerHeight + filterHeight + "px";
}
factory.removeUnit = function(value, unit) {

    return value.replace(unit, '');
}
return factory;
```

});

And then in the controller write the following:

```
  angular.module('app',['ui.grid']).controller('AppController', ['uiGridConstants', function(uiGridConstants) {

  ...

  // Execute this when you have $scope.gridData loaded...
  $scope.gridHeight = uiGridService.getGridHeight($scope.gridData);
```

And at the HTML file:

```
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridData" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize style="height: {{gridHeight}}"></div>
```

When angular applies the style, it only has to look in the $scope.gridHeight variable and not to evaluate a complete function.

3) If you want to calculate dynamically the height of an expandable grid, it is more complicated. In this case, you can set expandableRowHeight property. This fixes the reserved height for each subgrid.

```
    $scope.gridData = {
        enableSorting: true,
        multiSelect: false,  
        enableRowSelection: true,
        showFooter: false,
        enableFiltering: true,    
        enableSelectAll: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false, 
        enableGridMenu: true,
        noUnselect: true,
        expandableRowTemplate: 'subGrid.html',
        expandableRowHeight: 380,   // 10 rows * 30px + 40px (header) + 40px (filters)
        onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {

            gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope, function(row){
                var height = parseInt(uiGridService.removeUnit($scope.jdeNewUserConflictsGridHeight,'px'));
                var changedRowHeight = parseInt(uiGridService.getGridHeight(row.entity.subGridNewUserConflictsGrid, true));

                if (row.isExpanded)
                {
                    height += changedRowHeight;                    
                }
                else
                {
                    height -= changedRowHeight;                    
                }

                $scope.jdeNewUserConflictsGridHeight = height + 'px';
            });
        },
        columnDefs :  [
                { field: 'GridField1', name: 'GridField1', enableFiltering: true }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: gridOptions.data.length results in the length of the string rather than the length of the array, in my case "referenceData.Subscriptions" = 21 chars. If defining the data property to be a string value,  e.g. 
` $scope.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnResizing: true,
                data: 'referenceData.Subscriptions',`

Answer (score 1):

tony's approach does work for me but when do a console.log, the function getTableHeight get called too many time(sort, menu click...)

I modify it so the height is recalculated only when i add/remove rows. Note: tableData is the array of rows

```
$scope.getTableHeight = function() {
   var rowHeight = 30; // your row height
   var headerHeight = 30; // your header height
   return {
      height: ($scope.gridData.data.length * rowHeight + headerHeight) + "px"
   };
};

$scope.$watchCollection('tableData', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.grid')).css($scope.getTableHeight());
});
```

Html

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridData" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am late to the game but I found a nice solution. I created a custom attribute directive all you need to do is pass in the gridApi and it will automatically calculate the height. It also subscribes to the pagination change event so if the user changes page size it will resize.

```js
class UIGridAutoResize implements ng.IDirective {
    link: (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => void;
    scope: { gridApi: "=" };
    restrict = "A";

    private previousValue: string;
    private isValid: boolean = true;
    private watch: any;

    constructor($timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) {
        UIGridAutoResize.prototype.link = (scope: ng.IScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes) => {
            const gridOptions = scope.$eval(attrs.uiGrid) as any;
            const gridApi = scope.$eval(attrs.gridResize) as any;

            gridApi.core.on.rowsRendered(scope, () => {
                $timeout(() => {
                    this.autoSizeGrid(element, attrs, gridOptions, gridApi, false);
                }, 100);
            });

            gridApi.core.on.filterChanged(scope, () => {
                this.autoSizeGrid(element, attrs, gridOptions, gridApi, false);
            });

            if (attrs.uiGridPagination === "") {
                gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged(null, () => {
                    this.autoSizeGrid(element, attrs, gridOptions, gridApi, true);
                });
            }

            angular.element(window).resize(() => {
                $timeout(() => {
                    this.autoSizeGrid(element, attrs, gridOptions, gridApi, false);
                }, 100);
            });
        };
    }

    static Factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($timeout: ng.ITimeoutService) => {
            return new UIGridAutoResize($timeout);
        };

        directive["$inject"] = ["$timeout"];

        return directive;
    }

    private autoSizeGrid(element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: ng.IAttributes, gridOptions: any, gridApi: any, isPaginationChanged: boolean) {
        gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();

        // Clear empty grid message 
        angular.element(element.parent()).find("#emptyGridMessage").remove();
        element.find(".ui-grid-viewport").css("display", "");

        if (attrs.hidePageSize === "") {
            element.find(".ui-grid-pager-row-count-picker").css("display", "none");
        }

        let rowCount = gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length;

        const headerElements = element.find(".ui-grid-header");
        let headerHeight = 2;

        if (headerElements.length > 1) { // If we have more than one header element the grid is using grouping
            const headerElement = angular.element(headerElements[1]);
            headerHeight += headerElement.height();
        } else {
            headerHeight += headerElements.height();
        }

        if (attrs.uiGridPagination === "") {
            if (rowCount < 1) {
                gridOptions.enablePagination = false;
                gridOptions.enablePaginationControls = false;
                element.css("height", (rowCount * 30) + headerHeight - 2);
                element.find(".ui-grid-viewport").css("display", "none");
                angular.element("<div id='emptyGridMessage' style='font-size: 1em; width: 100%; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #d4d4d4; padding: 7px 12px; color: #707070;'><span style='opacity: 0.95;'>There are no records.</span></div>").insertAfter(element);
            } else if (gridApi.core.getVisibleRows().length < gridOptions.paginationPageSize && !isPaginationChanged) {
                gridOptions.enablePagination = false;
                gridOptions.enablePaginationControls = false;
                element.css("height", (rowCount * 30) + headerHeight);
            } else {
                gridOptions.enablePagination = true;
                gridOptions.enablePaginationControls = true;              
                element.css("height", (rowCount * 30) + headerHeight);
            }
        } else {
            if (rowCount < 1) {
                element.css("height", (rowCount * 30) + headerHeight - 2);
                element.find(".ui-grid-viewport").css("display", "none");
                angular.element("<div id='emptyGridMessage' style='font-size: 1em; width: 100%; background-color: white; border: 1px solid #d4d4d4; padding: 7px 12px; color: #707070;'><span style='opacity: 0.95;'>There are no records.</span></div>").insertAfter(element);
            } else {
                element.css("height", (rowCount * 30) + headerHeight);
            }
        }

        // Add extra margin to prevent scroll bar and pager from overlapping content underneath
        const pagerHeight = element.find(".ui-grid-pager-panel").height();

        if (rowCount > 0) {
            if (pagerHeight > 0)
                element.css("margin-bottom", pagerHeight);
            else
                element.css("margin-bottom", 10);
        } else {
            if (pagerHeight > 0)
                angular.element(element.parent()).find("#emptyGridMessage").css("margin-bottom", pagerHeight);
            else 
                angular.element(element.parent()).find("#emptyGridMessage").css("margin-bottom", 10);
        }

        if (rowCount > gridOptions.paginationPageSize) // Sometimes paging shows all rows this fixes that
           gridApi.core.refresh();
    }
}
```

```html
<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" grid-resize="vm.gridApi" ui-grid-resize-columns ui-grid-pagination></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

following @tony's approach, changed the getTableHeight() function to

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="$ctrl.gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize style="{{$ctrl.getTableHeight()}}"></div>

getTableHeight() {
    var offsetValue = 365;
    return "height: " + parseInt(window.innerHeight - offsetValue ) + "px!important";
}
```

the grid would have a dynamic height with regards to window height as well.